# Swift async Task captures value too long

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, core-image, metalkit

I want to do some `async` processing in my `MTKView`'s `draw(_:)` method. For that I'm first getting the `currentDrawable` and then using it inside of a `Task`:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let currentDrawable = self.currentDrawable else { return }
    Task {
        // <image filtering>
        
        let destination = CIRenderDestination(width: Int(drawableSize.width),
                                              height: Int(drawableSize.height),
                                              pixelFormat: self.colorPixelFormat,
                                              commandBuffer: nil,
                                              mtlTextureProvider: { () -> MTLTexture in
                                                return currentDrawable.texture
                                              })
        try await asynContext.startTask(toClear: destination)
        try await asynContext.startTask(toRender: image, to: destination)
        currentDrawable.present()
    }
}
```

While this works, the performance is much worse than using a `DispatchQueue` or staying on the main thread.
It seems the `Task` is holding on to the drawable for much longer than its actual execution, which causes the next call to `currentDrawable` to stall when no more drawables are in the pool at the moment.
I assume the `Task` itself is still referenced/used by the concurrency runtime after its execution for a little while longer.

Is there a way to prevent that? Or, alternatively, to have the Task's `operation` block release the drawable early?

---

As by matt's request, a little more elaboration:

I want to move some computation Core Image is doing on the filter graph into a background queue to not block the main thread. For that, I created a little helper actor:

```
actor AsyncContext {

    private let context: CIContext

    init(context: CIContext) {
        self.context = context
    }

    @discardableResult
    func startTask(toClear destination: CIRenderDestination) throws -> CIRenderTask {
        return try self.context.startTask(toClear: destination)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func startTask(toRender image: CIImage, to destination: CIRenderDestination) throws -> CIRenderTask {
        return try self.context.startTask(toRender: image, to: destination)
    }

}
```

The actor should ensure that calls to `startTask(...)` are happening in a background queue (which they do).

I'm pretty confident that the actor itself is not the problem. It's the `Task` not getting released in time, I think.

Comment: Merely declaring a Task does not put you on a background thread, so what is the point of your code?

Comment: Yes, true. I'm calling some methods on an `actor` in the `<rendering>` part.

Comment: Well, as you know very well, we cannot see your code unless you show it.

Comment: @matt Done editing .

Comment: Interesting. Shouldn't you be calling `currentDrawable.present()` on the main actor?

Comment: I also thought it's necessary at first, but turns out it's not. `present` will actually schedule it for presentation at an opportune time anyways.